# What is the value of the sum of $e^{i(-ak^2 + bk)}$ when $k$ goes through every integer?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, fourier-series, laurent-series

I'm doing a physics question sheet and I stumbled upon a series of the kind
$$
\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} e^{i(-ak^{2}+bk)}
$$
Where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers with $a>0$.

I have no idea how to do this and not even Mathematica will calculate it for me!

Comment: We cannot guarantee that the series will converge: consider the case $a = \pi, b = 0$ and it's rather clear that our summand is $1$ for even $k$ and $-1$ for odd $k$ and we have a classic divergent series.

Answer (score 1):

This has the structure of a  [theta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function) but the series  need not converge unless  $a$ is restricted to a complex half-plane ( $a$ cannot be purely real).